# Was there a plan for Otto Mink's automatic pistol?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agent-carter

In *Agent Carter*, episode 4 of season 1, "The Blitzkrieg Button", [Otto Mink](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Otto_Mink) repairs an [automatic pistol](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Automatic_Pistol), uses it on some subordinates who had failed him, and then set off to attack Agent Carter. He's stopped by another character, whose identity I won't mention unless necessary, as it's a bit of a spoiler for the episodes prior to this one, who promptly kills him and confiscates the pistol for their own use. As far as I know, it did not show up again in the series. It seemed a bit odd for such a unique, and advanced weapon to be introduced into the series, show up in one episode, and then not show up again. Were there plans for the pistol? Issues with operation? Plot changes caused by actor availability?

Comment: There is nothing special or overly fantastic about Otto Mink’s auto pistol. Various gunsmiths had been inventing and perfecting automatic pistols including “gatling” type action since the late 1800’s. By Carter & Mink’s time this kind of gun is a sort of anachronistic curiosity belonging in personal collection or museum than supervillains being able to change the tide of war with one.